# Extract values from list and concatenate it to a string

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contains various company names I am trying to extract each item from the list and concatenate it to a string. Here is how i do it:

```
stock = ['TATACHEM', 'SNOWMAN']
for element in stock:
    z1='NSE:'+element
```

The Issue I face over here is that when I see z1 it contains only last element of the list concatenated with the string 'NSE' and the resulting output is:

```
NSE:SNOWMAN
```

However when I print all the element of the list it gives me all the elements. That is when I use:

```
for element in stock:
    print(element)
```

It gives me a list of both the elements in the list:

```
TATACHEM
SNOWMAN
```

How do I modify my code above so as to get the following output:

```
NSE:SNOWMAN
NSE:TATACHEM
```

Comment: You *assign* to `z1`. `z1` can only hold a single value, so yes, the latter assignment overrides all previous assignments. Did you mean to create a new *list* into which you put those new strings?

Comment: @deceze you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `z1 = "NSE: " + "\nNSE: ".join(stock)`

Edit: If you want z1 as a list, then you could use list comprehension:

```py
z1 = ["NSE:" + i for i in stock]
```